# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException

Tags: java, ios, selenium

1. I am getting error org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
   once i execute the code

   package SignUp;

   import java.net.URL; import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit; import
   org.openqa.selenium.By; import
   org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities; import
   org.testng.annotations.BeforeT`enter code here`est; import
   org.testng.annotations.Test;

   import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;

   public class SignUPBaseclass {      public IOSDriver driver;
       @BeforeTest     public void SignUp1() throws Exception  {
               DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();           capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.0");
               capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
               capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.3");
               capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 5S Plus");
               capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/sumit/Desktop/Project
   /FSFosh-1.ipa");            IOSDriver driver = new IOSDriver(new
   URL("http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub"), capabilities);
               driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

   ```
                   }
   ```

   @Test  public void Flow(){      driver.findElement(By.name("JOIN US
   FREE!")).click();       //AppiumCapabilities App_Cap = new
   AppiumCapabilities();       //App_Cap.driver.findElement(By.name("JOIN
   US FREE!")).click();

   ```
           } /*@AfterClass //public void tearDown()  {     AppiumCapabilities App_Cap = new AppiumCapabilities();  App_Cap.driver.quit(); }*/
   ```

   }

   Error Message

   [TestNG] Running:
   /private/var/folders/6r/_2b4t0zj1tj95nkmxmj9c5n40000gp/T/testng-eclipse-2068198674/testng-customsuite.xml

   log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
   (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies). log4j:WARN
   Please initialize the log4j system properly. FAILED CONFIGURATION:
   @BeforeTest SignUp1 org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
   A new session could not be created. (Original error: Requested a new
   session but one was in progress) (WARNING: The server did not
   provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 469
   milliseconds Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b',
   time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40' System info: host:
   'Appster-Sumit-Nagar.local', ip: '172.16.17.71', os.name: 'Mac OS
   X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.3', java.version:
   '1.7.0_80' Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver     at
   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
   Method)     at
   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
       at
   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
       at
   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
       at
   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
       at
   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
       at
   io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:180)
       at
   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
       at
   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
       at
   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:158)
       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:109)
       at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.(IOSDriver.java:23)
       at SignUp.SignUPBaseclass.SignUp1(SignUPBaseclass.java:23)  at
   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)     at
   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
       at
   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
       at
   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
       at
   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
       at
   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
       at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:648)     at
   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:616)  at
   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)    at
   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)    at
   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)     at
   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)    at
   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)    at
   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)     at
   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)   at
   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)    at
   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)     at
   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:112)   at
   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:205)    at
   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:176)

   SKIPPED: Flow

   ===============================================
       Default test
       Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1

   ## Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0

   ===============================================

   Default suite

   Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1 Configuration Failures: 1,

   ## Skips: 0

   [TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]:
   194 ms [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@be71839:
   322 ms [TestNG] Time taken by
   org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@118e0f0f: 119 ms [TestNG]
   Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@1f80ce47: 21
   ms [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@3f611531:
   88 ms [TestNG] Time taken by
   org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@582ed819: 8 msenter code
   here

Comment: Could you confirm that no other session is running when you try to run your test? Edit - Try restarting your Appium server, it is possible a previous session wasn't ended properly.

Comment: I have restarted  my appium Server but no benefits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved here , 
here i just created "RemoteWebDriver" object instead of IOSDriver ..

```
public class SignUPBaseclass extends Testbase {
public RemoteWebDriver driver;

@BeforeTest
public RemoteWebDriver SignUp1() throws Throwable  {

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.0");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.3");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 5S Plus");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/sumit/Desktop/Project /FSFosh-1.ipa");
     driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    return driver;
}
```